# Preserving lists in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, list, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a yaml file with some value as a list on multiple lines:

```
my_list: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
          11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

If I load and then dump this using ruamel.yaml it does two things:

1. it puts the list in one line
2. it adds a space between items

```
my_list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

is there a way to leave a list alone using ruamel.yaml?

I have tried looking for documentation on ruamel.yaml but I can't find too much about this. I know that there is LiteralScalarString which helps for strings, but I sort of need an equivalent for lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says in the [introduction to the documentation](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)

> block style and key ordering are kept, so you can diff the round-tripped source

It will not preserve breaks (or comments) inserted within flow-style sequence elements (or flow-style mapping key-values).
All such flow sequences are normalised to have a space before the scalar if preceded by a flow-sequence element indicator (`,`). There is no easy fix of searching for the string `', '` and replacing it with `','` because of that.

The `LiteralScalarString` doesn't do much special, execpt keeping line breaks during dumping. The `FoldedScalarString` does something more complex in preserving the positions where the original string was folded while allowing you to use the string as if normally loaded. To preserve the "folds" in a flow style sequence, a list of indices is kept on the object. You could use such a mechanism to "fold" flow-style sequences.

However since newlines in block-style are kept as (empty) comments it is more likely that ruamel.yaml will at some point support intra flow-style collection comments (indexed to an element, key or value) and that would give you your newline in a different way.